# Eslint angular and jasmine: is not defined no-undef

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, eslint

I am trying to lint my angular code using angular, eslint:recommended and the jasmine plugin recommended settings. However I get is not defined errors on the jasmine stuff.
My eslint file looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": ["jasmine"],
  "extends": ["angular", "eslint:recommended", 
  "plugin:jasmine/recommended"],
  "rules": {
   "quotes": [ 2, "single"],
   "strict": [2, "global"],
   "semi": ["error", "always"],
   "angular/on-watch": "warn"
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

> 3:1 error 'describe' is not defined no-undef
>
> 4:5 error 'it' is not defined no-undef
>
> 5:9 error 'expect' is not defined no-undef
>
> 7:5 error 'it' is not defined no-undef
>
> 8:9 error 'expect' is not defined no-undef

And in my `package.json` I have version `2.3.0` for `eslint` and `1.8.1` for `eslint-plugin-jasmine`. I also have version `0.5.0` for `eslint-config-angular` and `1.0.0` for `eslint-plugin-angular`.

I have also tried without specifying the `"plugins": ["jasmine"]` in my `eslint` file but then I get an error telling me the jasmine rules are not defined (eg `Definition for rule 'jasmine/no-focused-tests' was not found`).

Comment: And for *angular* use a global, like the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552223/1038726

Answer (score 45):

Adding

```
"env": {
 "jasmine": true
}
```

solved the problem. This was the suggestion that i got through the github page of the eslint jasmine plugin.

Comment: for those who are confused by all the configuration files (as I am): the setting goes to `eslintrc`

Comment: It's located on the top level of `,eslintrc.json`

Answer (score 7):

The way I found to configure the validations for all Jasmine functions and do it in a single place, but still flag them when they are used in a "non-spec" file is as follows.

Have the common configuration defined at config level. Then, for those specific configurations (such as Typescript or Jasmin) do an override. That way, the "global configuration" is applied only to specific files.

```json
{
    "env": {
        "jasmine": true
    },
    "files": ["**/*.spec.js"]
}
```

Fragment of `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config}
 */
module.exports = {
    "env": {...},
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
            ],
            "files": ["**/*.ts"],
            "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": "tsconfig.json",
                "tsconfigRootDir": __dirname
            },
            "plugins": [
                "@typescript-eslint"
            ]
        },
        // This is the important part
        {
            "env": {
                "jasmine": true
            },
            "files": ["**/*.spec.js"] 
        }
    ],
    "root": true,
    "rules": {...}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

With [this rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) set, any variable non explicitly declared causes a warning.
You can set at the top of your *spec* file:

```
/* global describe it expect */
```

Comment: Hej, that works. But i think it is quite ugly to put that line in all my test files. I thought that would have been something the jasmine plugin fixed? Is there another way so that i put this in one spot and it is applied to all my spec files?

Comment: The rule is doing its job: warning you the usage of a global variable. You can disable this rule when linting your .spec files (run eslint with separate settings for .spec and code. Or Don't use linting at all on your spec files. Or disable this rule altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `/* eslint-env jasmine */` to the top of your `.spec.ts` files. This is basically the same solution as the one proposed by Geert, but with a per-file solution. The subtle difference is that it will still be an error to use some of the globally defined test methods like `describe()` and `it()` in your non-test files.

(There is probably a clever way to set up ESLint, so that you don't have add this line to all the `.spec.ts` files.)