# Global variables in Javascript and ESLint

Tags: javascript, variables, global, eslint

I have got multiple javascript files and I have defined some global variable in a file which loads before the others.
As a consequence all of the files loaded after the first have access to the global variable.
However ESLint shows the global variable as "not defined". I don't want to change the rules of ESLint and I would like to find an elegant way to get rid of these error messages.
Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: `->` http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals . ESLint's documentation is great IMO, you should take a look at that.

Comment: _"an elegant way to get rid of these error messages"_ - personally I would prefer to remove the global variables!

Answer (score 190):

I don't think hacking ESLint rules per file is a great idea.

You should rather define `globals` in `.eslintrc` or `package.json`.

For .eslintrc:

```
"globals": {
    "angular": true
}
```

For `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "globals": {
        "angular": true
    }
}
```

Check https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals

Comment: It may be worth noting that you set the global variable to `true` if you can assign the variable to something else and `false` if it shouldn't be reassigned.

Comment: Linking documentation is a virtue that is much appreciated on stackoverflow answers.

Comment: @RomainG there is already link below ;)
But I'll add one for you

Comment: Moreover, you can actually make them `"readonly"` or `"writable"`.

Comment: global, not globals, in my version of eslint.

Answer (score 156):

You can add globals either per file or in your config.
If you don't want to change your config, you'll have to add the used globals in every file.

From the [Specifying globals](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals) ESLint docs section:

> To specify globals using a comment inside of your JavaScript file, use the following format:
>
> ```
> /* global var1, var2 */
> ```
>
> This defines two global variables, `var1` and `var2`. If you want to optionally specify that these global variables can be written to (rather than only being read), then you can set each with a with a "writable" flag:
>
> ```
> /* global var1:writable, var2:writable */
> ```

Older versions of ESLint used `var1:false` to indicate that `var1` should be read-only.