# How can I use ESLint no-unused-vars for a block of code?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I need to disable some variable checks in `ESLint`.

Currently, I am using this code, but am not getting the desired result:

```js
/* eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "caughtErrorsIgnorePattern": "Hey" }] */
export type Hey = {
  a: string,
  b: object
}
```

Two questions:

- Is there a variant which can enable `no-unused-vars` for a block of code?

Something like...

```js
/* eslint rule disable"*/

// I want to place my block of code, here

/* eslint rule disable"*/
```

- Or could I make `Hey` a global variable so that it can be ignored everywhere?

Comment: See [adding global variable in ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552041/global-variables-in-javascript-and-eslint)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Javascript and ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552041/global-variables-in-javascript-and-eslint)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To disable the `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` warning:

- ###### For the current line:

```
const unusedVar = 1; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

- ###### For the next line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const unusedVar = 1;
```

- ###### For a block:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
const unusedVar1 = 1;
const unusedVar2 = 2;
/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```

Notice that you have to use a block comment to toggle the behavior in this case.

## Original answer

Just use pair of lines:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

// ... your code here with unused vars...

/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

Comment: I have tried with no success, the error is thrown by standardjs

Comment: Hacking linting rules for something that is built in to ESLint (defining globals) is pretty frowned upon.

Comment: Good habit is to set these on .eslintrc. This example might not be the wisest way normally, but I can imagine that there comes cases when you are forced to do this kind of things.

Comment: @Radex, have you checked your eslint version? Could it be so old that it does not support eslint-disable? I checked my example before posting it to here and it functioned, so I think your problem is now elsewhere in a setup.

Comment: @Ville Venäläinen, Your answer worked for me.  I'm using eslint version 4.18.1

Comment: Glad to help :) I guess the thing is up to eslint version.

Comment: A shame it does'nt work with `// eslint-disable no-unused-vars`

Comment: If using `TypeScript`, do this `/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */`. @Tim J answer was [helpful in that cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57610342/10849438)

Comment: A handy quick-fix when your editor and a project don't agree on how a block should be indented (using the `indent` rule, of course)

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, you can disable the rule for one line:

```js
// Based on your Typescript example

export type Hey = { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  a: string,
  b: object
}
```

Answer (score 23):

One more option...

```
function doStuff({
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  unused,
  usedA,
  usedB
}) {
```

Answer (score 15):

For typescript eslint users just add this at the end of line you wish to ignore:

```
// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 9):

If you've got multiple overlapping rules that you want to ignore (e.g. typescript and standard js), you can specify more than one rule to ignore by separating by a comma:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering why it doesnt work with

```
// eslint-disable some-rule/specific-rule
```

just enclose the same disable statement in multiline comment and it will work.

```
/* eslint-disable some-rule/specific-rule  */
```

encapsulating eslint rules in multiline comment work for the whole block.
So if you put multiline comment at the start of a function, it will disable that rule for the whole function block. If you put it at the start of a file, it will disable that rule for the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

Define **ESLint** configuration in `package.json` like this

```js
{
  "plugins": [
    // ...
    "react-hooks"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For inline comments, this is the only one that worked for me:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```