# Issues woriking with angularjs in vscode editor

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

am using angular in vscode but 'angular' is underline red saying that

```
angular is not defined: 'export namespace angular'
```

here is the code:

```
angular.module('kontrol', ['ngRoute'])config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$provide', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')}
```

Comment: Add `angular` to the list of globals in your `.eslintrc.js` file (or whatever the appropriate linter configuration file is)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Javascript and ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552041/global-variables-in-javascript-and-eslint)

Answer (score 1):

You should  define globals in **[`.eslintrc`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals)**

```
"globals": {
    "angular": true
}
```

Comment: where do i find the .eslintrc, i navigated into the eslint folder but i could see the .eslintrc file so i added  the "globals": {
    "angular": true
}

Comment: @yaxx https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals