# How to make eslint ignore 'eventbus is not defined' errors in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

Eslint says that eventbus is not defined. I agree with him, it's not imported. But I had defined it in main.js (the root of my app). The app works fine but I see the error all the time. Is there any way to make Eslint ignore it

I've tried to put // eslint-disable-next-line before every line where I use eventbus, but it is not very good, you know.

There are screenshots:

using the eventbus https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR7Fm.png

defining the eventbus https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS9jN.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Javascript and ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552041/global-variables-in-javascript-and-eslint)

Comment: I think that other answer is all that you need. Good luck!

Comment: And the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals