# JS: ESlint saying undefined method but it is from external script

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a class that I am using as my video player.  On my main page, I have a script tag to include Amazon's IVS video player external script.  That has a lot of methods in it, including `registerIVSTech` which I am calling in this class :

```
class myClass {
     constructor(myData) {
          this.data = myData;
     }
     init() {
        registerIVSTech();
     }
}

export default myClass;
```

However, when I run ESLint, it says:

```
 error  'registerIVSTech' is not defined           no-undef
```

but it is defined.  I used a `debugger` and the value of it is there since the IVS scripts loads on the page, the class has access to it.  Is there a way around this without using npm modules?

Comment: Show the whole code

Comment: I would define this as a global in the eslint config. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552223/1691

Answer (score 1):

You can disable eslint rules. In this case add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef` the line before you call registerIVSTech.